# multiprocessing hangs xgboost scoring

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, multiprocessing, xgboost

I am trying to score multiple datasets at the same time using multiprocessing. The following code hangs on run, yet when I run score on the base_model outside of the pool it executes instantly.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

titanic = pd.read_csv('titanic.csv')
titanic['Age'].fillna(titanic['Age'].mean(), inplace=True) #fill all missing values with the average
#create indicator for cabin because there is  areason it was missing
titanic['Cabin_ind'] = np.where(titanic['Cabin'].isnull(), 0, 1)
#convert sex to numeric
gender_num = {'male': 0, 'female': 1}
titanic['Sex'] = titanic['Sex'].map(gender_num)
#drop uncessary variables
titanic.drop(columns=['Cabin', 'Embarked', 'Name', 'Ticket'], inplace=True)
features = titanic.drop(columns=['Survived'])
labels = titanic['Survived']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=.2, random_state=42)

from xgboost import XGBClassifier

base_model = XGBClassifier(objective='binary:logistic', nthread=4, seed=27, scoring='auc')
base_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

import multiprocessing as mp

def my_func(X_test, y_test, base_model):
    val = base_model.score(X_test, y_test)
    print(val)

def main():
    to_pass = [(X_test, y_test, base_model)]
    pool = mp.Pool(1)
    pool.starmap(my_func, to_pass)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with `XGBoost` and `multiprocessing` is that you don't know what `XGBoost` does under the hood when you pass it to multiprocessing. This is a common thing not only with XGBoost but other libraries too and I have found many of them hang when you use different processes to speed up your work.

What I tend to do is to save the model and then use multiprocessing to create a new XGBClassifier and load the model from there. It is much safer and I am more certain nothing weird is gonna happen.

Here is an example

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


def get_data():
    titanic = pd.read_csv('titanic.csv', usecols=['Age', 'Cabin', 'Sex', 'Survived'])
    # fill all missing values with the average
    titanic['Age'] = titanic['Age'].fillna(titanic['Age'].mean())
    # create indicator for cabin because there is  areason it was missing
    titanic['Cabin_ind'] = np.where(titanic['Cabin'].isna(), 0, 1)

    # convert sex to numeric
    titanic['Sex'] = np.where(titanic['Sex'] == 'male', 0, 1)

    # convert Survived to numeric
    titanic['Survived'] = np.where(titanic['Survived'] == 'yes', 1, 0)

    features = titanic[['Age', 'Sex', 'Cabin_ind']]
    labels = titanic['Survived']
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
    return X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test


def train_model(X_train, y_train):
    print('Training model')
    base_model = XGBClassifier(objective='binary:logistic', nthread=4, seed=27, scoring='auc', use_label_encoder=False)
    base_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    base_model.save_model('model.json')


def score_model(i, X_test, y_test):
    print('{}: Scoring model'.format(i))
    base_model = XGBClassifier(objective='binary:logistic', nthread=4, seed=27, scoring='auc', use_label_encoder=False)
    base_model.load_model('model.json')
    score = base_model.score(X_test, y_test)
    y_pred = base_model.predict(X_test)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    return i, score, accuracy


def main():
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = get_data()
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        task = executor.submit(train_model, X_train, y_train)
        task.result()

    tasks = []
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        # You can split your test here, I am passing it as a whole
        for i in range(10):
            # I also use i in function to identify result later in case of out of order completion
            task = executor.submit(score_model, i, X_test, y_test)
            tasks.append(task)

    for task in as_completed(tasks):
        i, score, accuracy = task.result()
        print('Task {} completed: score={}, accuracy={}'.format(i, score, accuracy))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

EDIT:

1. As discussed [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/4246) the recommendation is to initialize xgboost after forking, so I train `XGBoost` in another process to avoid locking
2. When you use `XGBoost` it is good to force `use_label_encoder=False`. The reason is that `XGBoost`, at least on my computer complains about

```sh
UserWarning: The use of label encoder in XGBClassifier is
deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

To remove this warning, do the following:
1) Pass option use_label_encoder=False when constructing XGBClassifier object; and
2) Encode your labels (y) as integers starting with 0, i.e. 0, 1, 2, ..., [num_class - 1].
```

3. Try to avoid using `inplace` in `pandas`, as discussed [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529) thoroughly
4. Use `max_workers=some_cpu_number_that_makes_sense` to use many cpus.
5. I have trained a lot of things with `XGBoost` and to my experience you don't really need `multiprocessing` with it, it is pretty fast even with a 2 GB dataset. Unless you have a really really big dataset...

csv I used

```
Age,Cabin,Sex,Survived,Embarked,Name,Ticket
,,male,yes,,,
19,,male,no,,,
20,1,female,yes,,,
25,2,male,no,,,
,3,female,yes,,,
40,3,male,yes,,,
,3,female,yes,,,
,,female,yes,,,
,3,male,no,,,
15,3,female,yes,,,
```

Comment: I am getting an odd error - AttributeError: 'XGBClassifier' object has no attribute '_le' when trying to score the test data. I don't see too much about this online any thoughts? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you provide some sample csv (as minimal as possible) and version of xgoost you use (which OS)?

Comment: I updated my answer, I tested this on my machine and it works, please make sure you don't use a label encoder. This problem comes from label encoding the labels.